# Using NSPredicate with to-many relationship to obtain parent object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

Maybe it's because I haven't slept in 3 days, but this one is really throwing me. I'm in the early stages, but here is what I am wanting to do, obtain the parent `ManagedObject` knowing the child - using the object itself, not an attribute.

Example:

Entity A: Store (Attributes could be: storeName, storeAddress, etc... item(relationship))

Entity B: Item (Attributes could be: itemName, storename(duplicated, when item added to db), store(relationship))

These have a to-many relationship - Each Item has one Store. However, I could buy the same item more than once from the same store, or from different stores with the same name - such as a Bag of M&M's from Von's. As a result, I would get duplicates if I used:

```
Item *aItem = [[itemArrayController selectedObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

NSPredicate *predicateTemplate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"storeName like %@", aItem.storename];
```

I tried this and other variations (without success):

```
NSPredicate *predicateTemplate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"item like %@", Item];
```

The error is that I can't use this with to-many relationship - ok, understandable but what can I use?

Yes, I could introduce an attribute that would link them together, but I am trying to avoid this. Core Data links these together already, there should be a way capitalize on that.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Store` -> `Item` is a to-many relationship, you need to find `stores` with (presumably) ANY `item` that matches.  The predicate for this would be:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY item == %@", aItem];
```

Alternatively, you can just use the inverse relationship to access the parent:

```
Store *myStore = [aItem valueForKey:@"store"];
```

or, if you have created subclasses of `NSManagedObject` you can use the dot notation:

```
Store *myStore = aItem.store;
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple, that's what I needed - thank you.